# Google Ads API: want to find the cost data through API

Tags: google-ads-api

[image: The Image shows the overview of ads related to an ad account, I need to find the cost marked in the pic through API]

The Image shows the overview of ads related to an ad account, I need to find the cost marked in the pic through API

I tried with

```
ad_group metrics.average_cost, metrics.cost, 
    account_budget.amount_served_micros, 
    account_budget.total_adjustments_micros, 
    account_budget.proposed_spending_limit_micros,
    account_budget_proposal.account_budget,
    account_budget_proposal.approved_spending_limit_micros,      account_budget_proposal.proposed_spending_limit_micros, 
    campaign.campaign_budget, 
    campaign_budget.amount_micros, 
    campaign_budget.total_amount_micros
```

most of the values I got in these are zero or not relevant to the cost in the overview (marked in pic) . Can someone help me find the cost value( which is marked in the image) in the ads overview screen through GoogleAds API.

Comment: Can you share your code and/or any errors you get?

Comment: I didnt get any error, I want to get the cost value shown in the pic through API , from which API endpoint can i fetch it ?

Comment: Is that the total cost value for the account?

Comment: Yes cost spent by the account in that date range

Answer (score 0):

Your query isn't a complete query. We don't know what resource you're querying. For example, why are you requesting budgets?

If you share your code, we might be able to help you more. But you need to query the campaign costs from the campaign resource and aggregate yourself.

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v12/campaign?hl=en